# React search the text in an array of objects on Onchange of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to manipulate a table data on the basis of the search in the table. So, what I have is this type of data:

```
this.props.datalist = {
    "content": [{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "companyId": null,
        "title": "Senior/ Lead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "java"
    },{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075011",
        "companyId": null,
        "title": "ead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "angular"
    }]
}
```

In this I have this data coming from my `redux state. So I show this to user in the table form by passing this as a props.

I have a search field:

```
<input type="text"
       id="searchJob"
       className="form-control-sm border-0 flex-grow-1"
       value={this.state.search}
       placeholder="Company Name / Technology / Job title"
       onChange={this.onInputChnage} 
/>
    <i className="fa fa-search search-job"></i>

 onInputChnage = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    }) 
  }


<div className="col-12 pr-0 pl-0">
            <UserJobsTabel jobList={filteredList} />
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here , I got the filtered data in this array using filter

```
 [{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd00507501051",
        "companyId": null,
        "title": "Senior/ Lead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "java"
    },{
        "id": "5b7d4a566c5fd005075011",
        "companyId": null,
        "title": "ead UI Developer",
        "jobDescription": null,
        "technology": "angular"
    }]
```

Now, while setting state,

I am doing like this.

```
this.setState({ search: data })
```

If I want to set the state as  with key like `"content": [{}]` like this then How can I do this ?

Because the way I am using it is like,

```
{this.props.dataList && this.props.dataList.content && this.props.dataList.content.length > 0 && this.props.dataList.content.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt).map((item, key) => {
```

What I want to do is that the table data has two keys. One is `title` and `Technolgoy` now, search happens then it should check in the object and return the matched objects and that will be displayed on table.
Now if search has again nothing then it should show the default data that was present. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a variable in the `render` method containing the filtered `props.datalist` and use that for displaying.

something like

```js
render(){
   const { datalist:{content} } = this.props;
   const { search } = this.state;
   const filteredList = content.filter(job=>Object.values(job).some(value=>value.includes(search)));

   return (<div>
     //whatever
     {filteredList.map(job=>....)}
   </div>)
}
```

---

You could also do the filtering in the `onInputChnage` and store the filtered list in the local `state`.

Comment: There are two criterias there like it may be in Technology or in the title

Comment: And if there is nothing matching I need to show that nothing is matching and if user clears all that then it should show all data which was in that array

Comment: this data is coming directly from the application state that is redux

Comment: @ganeshk now it checks all properties. If you want to only test the specific two change the `Object.values(.)...` with `job.title.includes(search) || job.technology.includes(search)`.

Comment: Handle the case where no results are found in the rendering with something like `{filteredList.length ? filteredList.map(job=>....)} : <div>nothing found</div>}`

Comment: The case where the user clears the `search` box is already handled because all strings include the empty string.

Comment: about when there is nothing user has searched then how should I show all the previous data

Comment: @ganeshk just initialize the component state with `{search:''}`

Comment: Actually I got this errror TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined  as by it renders first time and that array does not have values in it it comes after api call

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/xZLCXajnPf2cQBzK?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview check this

Comment: const { jobs:{content} } = this.props;
    const { search } = this.state; 
    const filteredList = content.filter(job=>job.technology.includes(search));  used like this is the right way

Comment: Okay I will just check one thing that is the data is coming from the application state. So, I am confused there

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null getting this error

Comment: whenever it is the last one that time it gives that error

Comment: @ganesh that would happen if there was a job whose `.technology` or `.title` was `null`. Try using `(job.title && job.title.includes(search)) || (job.technology && job.technology.includes(search))` which also checks if those properties have a value before filtering on them.

Comment: Thanks I actually added one small question how to setstate with the key and array so could you please check this

Comment: And also because of that if I pass only filteredList data then it does not show anything . as it checks the conditions